# Spark structured streaming - unable to read data from socket

Tags: apache-spark, network-programming, spark-structured-streaming

I am learning Spark Structured streaming. I am trying to run the following program to read data from socket and print word counts.

```
        SparkConf conf = new SparkConf()
            .setAppName("StructuredStreamingWordCount")
            .setMaster("local[*]"); // Use a local Spark master for testing

    // Create a SparkSession
    SparkSession sparkSession = SparkSession.builder()
            .config(conf)
            .getOrCreate();

    sparkSession.sparkContext().setLogLevel("ERROR");

    Dataset<Row> lines = sparkSession.readStream().format("socket")
            .option("host", "localhost")
            .option("port", 1234)
            .load();

    System.out.println("streaming source ready : " + lines.isStreaming());
    // Split the lines into words and perform word count
    Dataset<Row> words = lines.selectExpr("explode(split(value, ' ')) as word");
    Dataset<Row> wordCounts = words.groupBy("word").count();
    try {
    // Print the word count results to the console
    StreamingQuery query = wordCounts.writeStream()
            .outputMode("complete") // Use "complete" mode for word count
            .format("console")
            .start();


        // Wait for the query to terminate (you can use query.awaitTermination() for a production application)
        query.awaitTermination();
    } catch (StreamingQueryException | TimeoutException e) {
        e.printStackTrace(); // Handle the exception or log it as needed
    }
```

I am trying to send messages using ncat command to get this to work. I am doing all this on a windows machine.

When I run this, the program errors out saying connection refused. Apparently, it is expecting data actively being sent to the port when it starts running. But I am not able to start the producer - ncat command errors out saying no connection could be established because target machine actively refused it.

How do I get this to work?